# Create a formula in excel to search between 2 sheets

Tags: excel

i have two excel sheets , sheet1 has column A ( name ) , columnB( Family Name ) and column C ( Date of Birth ) , total rows around 1800 . 
sheet2 has Column A ( name ) Column B ( Family Name ) , total rows 570 . 
i need a rule to search for A1 and  B2 in Sheet2 if they are existing in Sheet1 then display C3  .

thanks alot and Best Regards

Imad

Answer (score 1):

You can do as below:-

> > In sheet1, insert a column before DOB so DOB goes to D and the new inserted column is in C. In cell C2 give formula `=A2&"-"&B2`
> >
> > Do same for sheet2 in C column
> >
> > Go to the sheet 2 and type below formula in cell D2:- `=VLOOKUP(C2|Sheet1!$C$1:$D$2|2|0)`

This will fetch all DOB values from sheet1 and place it in sheet2 wherever a match is found

Answer (score 1):

You should use an Index Match formula entered as an array formula.
To enter an array formula don't just press enter but press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>

In C1 enter: `=Index(Sheet1!$A:$C,MATCH(1,(Sheet1!$A:$A=A1)*(Sheet1!$B:$B=B1),0),3)` And make sure to confirm the formula with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>

Edit:
As the layout changed.

In D1 enter: `=IF(C1=(Index(Sheet1!$A:$C,MATCH(1,(Sheet1!$A:$A=A1)*(Sheet1!$B:$B=B1),0),3)),"true","false")`

Comment: Dear Luuklag , thanks for your smooth and swift solution and reply . i add column C in Sheet2 ( birthday ) , so i need a rule to search for A1 AND B2 AND C3 in sheet2 if they are existing in Sheet1 then display " True"

Answer (score 1):

```
IF((Sheet1!A2:A1800=A2)*(Sheet1!B2:B1800=B2)*(Sheet1!C2:C1800=C2),TRUE)
```

Please enter this formula as an array formula in cell D2 at sheet 2

Comment: IF((Sheet1!A2:A1800=A2)*(Sheet1!B2:B1800=B2)*(Sheet1!C2:C1800=C2),TRUE) Please enter this formula as an array formula in cell D2 at sheet 2